# Entity Framework groupby day to day in month

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to do a groupby from the 16th of each months to the 15th of the next months.

Is it possible with Entity Framework or linq?

```
var result = await db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate > date)
                            .GroupBy(...)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What is the year timeframe? (e.g. what years are in the data, what is the oldest year?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work with EF and SQL, you can just do some date math to compute a "period" number for grouping. Basically, you convert each date to the month, offset by the 16th, plus add an offset for the year:

```
var result = await db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate > date)
                            .GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate.Month + 12*(o.OrderDate.Year - date.Year) - (o.OrderDate.Day >= 16 ? 0 : 1))
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Per @stuartd, here is how to get back the period for each group:

```
var resultp = result.Select(r => new {
                  PeriodBegin = new DateTime(date.Year + r.Key / 12 - (r.Key % 12 == 0 ? 1 : 0), r.Key % 12 == 0 ? 12 : r.key % 12, 16),
                  PeriodEnd = new DateTime(date.Year + r.Key / 12, r.Key % 12 + 1, 15),
                  Orders = r.ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a very neat and clever solution, which returns the same data as in my answer, and working in EF is a big bonus. I'm going to delete my answer, just mentioning that the only thing missing here IMO is a way to get back to the range that each group belongs to.

Comment: @stuartd I added some code to convert the period value back into begin and end dates.

Comment: Range solution just as neat, would upvote again if I could. BTW love your website, nostalgic goodness :)